# Install software on cloud

Tags: cloud, saas

I want to create a website where users can use software meant for windows. Software must be opened and stored online (at a cloud service). Is this possible without using a Virtual Machine? I believe this is concedered as a SaaS but do I need to create the software from scratch or can I use an existing one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of cloud desktop services which you can access via a browser - some examples are:

- https://www.mikogo.com/cloud-desktop/
- http://www.apps4rent.com/virtual-desktop.html

The broader technology is generally referred to as VDI - virtual desktop infrastructure. This essentially runs hosted OS's on VMs on a server. The server can either your own, a cloud server which you spin up and manage or a server managed by a cloud VDI provider. The last one is the one I think you are looking for.

Note that this approach does use a VM, but it is on the server side (or in the cloud) - I think it was a VM on the local machine you were trying to avoid.